# terminal doesn't work after running source ~/.bash_profile

Tags: macos, terminal

I'm a new python user. When I was installing postgresql and  running the following order:

```
$vi ~/.bash_profile

Add PATH=/usr/pgsql-9.2/bin:$PATH before export PATH.

$source ~/.bash_profile
```

My terminal became very strange. It seemed that I could not logout of the .bash_profile environment. When I use any basic comments like cd, open, etc., something strange happens.

This is my output:

```
MynametekiMacBook-Air:~ Myname$ cd Documents/

-bash: dirname: command not found

MynametekiMacBook-Air:Documents Myname$ open ~/.bash_profile

-bash: open: command not found

MynametekiMacBook-Air:Documents Myname$ easy_install pip

-bash: easy_install: command not found
```

How would I fix this?

Comment: Paste the `~/.bash_profile` here, so we can help you what going wrong.

Comment: I agree with @RayShih Post your `.bash_profile` as well as the output of `env` to a pastebin or something and provide it here.

Answer (score 0):

If you enter

```
$nano ~/.bash_profile
```

you will be able to edit your bash profile, you can remove the line that you added that is causing problems and try again, or see if there is a syntax error in what was entered. Once you've finished your edits you need to press `ctl+o` then `enter` to confirm and `ctl+x` to exit back to the bash prompt.

Answer (score 0):

run `/bin/mv ~/.bash_profile ~/.bp`. Close your terminal. Reopen and look at the new .bp file with `vim ~/.bp`. Fix any errors and run `mv ~/.bp ~/.bash_profile` to revert.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of running `source ~/.bash_profile` you can run the exports directly in the terminal:

```
$ export PATH=/usr/pgsql-9.2/bin:$PATH
```

Then try running `cd Documents` and the other commands in the terminal and it should work.

**Note:** When you run the exports directly in the terminal they become temporary variables. That means you'll need to run this command any time you want to run postgresql in a different terminal.

Answer (score -1):

Try `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/pgsql-9.2/bin` instead of `Add PATH=/usr/pgsql-9.2/bin:$PATH`. Because it looks like you made so your paths are being overwritten instead of being updated.

Comment: adding a path to `$PATH` shouldn't stop a terminal from working, even if the path doesn't exist. plus.. his paths are not being overwritten becuase he does have `:$PATH` in there. he is just prepending `/usr/pgsql-9.2/bin` to the `$PATH`.